# Add and remove a page from stack navigation on button click in Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

Is there any possibility to `Add` or `Remove` a page from a hierarchy of pages in `Xamarin.Forms`, `Android`? From a blank model to create a hierarchy with `Add` button and then to remove any pages, and then so `Save` the changes.

Comment: Yes, the documentation explicitly covers how to manage the navigation stack.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#manipulating-the-navigation-stack

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the specified page from the navigation stack.

```
// Remove page before Edit Page
this.Navigation.RemovePage (this.Navigation.NavigationStack [this.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2]);
```

For more details, please check the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.inavigation.removepage?view=xamarin-forms

And insert a page in the navigation stack before an existing page in the stack.

```
Navigation.InsertPageBefore (Page3, this);
```

For more details, please check the link below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.inavigation.insertpagebefore?view=xamarin-forms